# 1998 Mazda 626 LX with CEL and rough idle

Tags: rough-idle, mazda-626

I have a '98 Mazda 626 LX. About a month ago it suddenly started shaking really badly, so I took it to Midas for them to check the engine. They told me it needed a fuel flush, throttle body cleaning, and fuel system flush. They wanted a lot of money, so I took it to another place. They checked it, cleaned the throttle body and changed a bad fuel injector.

Then the car ran great and the acceleration problem went away. But yesterday the check engine came back on (flashing). The car wants to turn off on me again. And it smells like something I can't put my finger on. I checked the fuel injectors they are all good.

Any ideas. It has been idling low since I got the car 6 years ago.

Comment: Is the smell something like rotten eggs? Also, how did you check the fuel injectors? and this is the 4-cyl?